# What is G.I.S for beginner?

Tags: gis-principle

I am 13 and I have an assessment on G.I.S soon and I don't have a clue what it is.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Your question has been answered previously: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-do-i-explain-what-gis-is-for-the-11-year-old-kid. I encourage you to take the GIS SE tour to learn how this site works: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour.

Comment: Since you have an internet connection there are plenty of resources online on this subject.  You need to put in more effort than to just ask a site like this to do your research for you.  You can start here  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system

Comment: I think it is too much to down vote 13 yo question. +1 from me